# Cannot find module 'axios'

Tags: node.js, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am coding a small program for Firebase Functions, using node.js.  I always install my node modules using npm and i also installed axios using npm only.

However when I do `firebase deploy` I get this error:

[image]

This is my package-lock.json

```
{
  "requires": true,
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": {
      "version": "0.19.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/axios/-/axios-0.19.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-1uvKqKQta3KBxIz14F2v06AEHZ/dIoeKfbTRkK1E5oqjDnuEerLmYTgJB5AiQZHJcljpg1TuRzdjDR06qNk0DQ==",
      "requires": {
        "follow-redirects": "1.5.10",
        "is-buffer": "^2.0.2"
      }
    },
    "debug": {
      "version": "3.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/debug/-/debug-3.1.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-OX8XqP7/1a9cqkxYw2yXss15f26NKWBpDXQd0/uK/KPqdQhxbPa994hnzjcE2VqQpDslf55723cKPUOGSmMY3g==",
      "requires": {
        "ms": "2.0.0"
      }
    },
    "follow-redirects": {
      "version": "1.5.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/follow-redirects/-/follow-redirects-1.5.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-0V5l4Cizzvqt5D44aTXbFZz+FtyXV1vrDN6qrelxtfYQKW0KO0W2T/hkE8xvGa/540LkZlkaUjO4ailYTFtHVQ==",
      "requires": {
        "debug": "=3.1.0"
      }
    },
    "is-buffer": {
      "version": "2.0.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer/-/is-buffer-2.0.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Kq1rokWXOPXWuaMAqZiJW4XxsmD9zGx9q4aePabbn3qCRGedtH7Cm+zV8WETitMfu1wdh+Rvd6w5egwSngUX2A=="
    },
    "ms": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ms/-/ms-2.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-VgiurfwAvmwpAd9fmGF4jeDVl8g="
    }
  }
}
```

When I remove `const axios = require('axios');` from my index.js, the rest of my code compiles and works just fine.

Any idea what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide package.json file instead of package-lock.json file

Comment: checkout my latest comment in my answer @asaak

Answer (score 41):

Looks like you are missing axios dependency in your `package.json` file.

Go to the functions directory and install axios. This will declare the axios dependency in the `package.json` for you. It works for me.

`npm install axios --save`

Redeploy your Cloud Function for Firebase using:

`firebase deploy`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'axios' or its corresponding type declarations.`

In `tsconfig.json` when I replaced,

```
{
...
"compilerOptions": {
   "module": "es2015"
   }
}
```

to

```
{
...
"compilerOptions": {
   "module": "CommonJS"
   }
}
```

the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

Command prompt then go to your folder and npm install axios. Finally, run the code. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not fix your issue, but might help others.
I have received an error message **"Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module 'axios'"** then I tried to install **axios** package by running the command **npm install axios** which fixed the problem.

- Note: I had package.json empty (not even a pair of curly braces). So running the nmp command was failing with error

  *npm install axios

  npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE*
  So I added a pair of curly braces {} to my package.json and executed the same command again fixed the issue.

  npm install axios
  added 2 packages, and audited 3 packages in 1s
  1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
  found 0 vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

after install:  npm install axios (in terminal)

import axios from 'axios'

The first axios should be taken from react and get it should be highlight

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).